# Why does RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly() return FALSE?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I wrote this code to register my assembly with COM-interface:

```
var rs = new RegistrationServices();
var b = rs.RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),                                                                                                     AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

At the end of execution **b** equals **false**. I don't understand what I am doing wrong? Is there any way to get more information why registration fails?

Thank you!

Comment: Without more information, all we can do is point you at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registerassembly%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): "the assembly contains no eligible types"

Comment: from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registerassembly%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) "otherwise false if the assembly contains no eligible types." - are there eligible types?

Comment: An "eligible type" is one that is decorated with the [ComVisible(true)] attribute and has a default constructor.  First make Regasm.exe work, then consider doing this.